# Will I be able to reactivate Windows after Motherboard Change?

Tags: windows-7, motherboard, reinstall, windows-activation

My computer is a custom-built machine, and I want to upgrade the motherboard, processor and RAM.  I am running Windows 7 Pro, and am using a valid volume license that we own.

After I upgrade the motherboard, I want to use my same hard drive and don't want to reinstall everything.

Will I be able to reactivate Windows with my volume license?

(there is another part to my endeavor, but I [posted a separate question](https://superuser.com/questions/1304093/can-i-use-the-same-hdd-as-it-is-after-i-change-my-motherboard) for it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is most likely yes.  A change of motherboard will always trigger a reactivation.  That vast majority of times, you can complete that without any problems.

Comment: I am using a volume license; I don't mind using another activation on that license - I am just concerned whether it will accept the same code again.

Comment: I don't see a problem there.  At my work place, we reformat staff computers when a user leaves, and install fresh copies of Windows on them when we give the same PC to a new user.  So we often reactivate fresh installations of Windows on the same PC, using the same key, and we rarely have a problem.  When we do, it's usually if a key has been reactivated numerous time.  I'm not sure if there's a hard limit, but if there is, it's more than two. :)

Comment: Worked like a charm.  I did have to reactivate, but there were no hangups whatsoever.

Answer (score -2):

Probably not, the motherboard is everything of the computer, but you Can transfer everything on a usb drive and transfer windows there too.