# Can I use the same HDD as it is after I change my motherboard?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, motherboard

My computer is a custom-built machine, and I want to upgrade the motherboard, processor and RAM. I am running Windows 7 Pro on a volume license.

After I upgrade the motherboard, I want to use my same hard drive and don't want to reinstall everything.

But I am changing from an Asus motherboard to an MSI motherboard.  My HDD has drivers on it for the Asus.  After I change the motherboards and use the same HDD, will it still boot?  I don't want to reinstall Windows.

(This is sort of part two to [my other question](https://superuser.com/questions/1304059/will-i-be-able-to-reactivate-windows-after-motherboard-change))

Comment: As long as both motherboards use the same interface (IDE, SATA, etc) then yes you can just swap them. Of course if you had anything installed specific to the old motherboard then it won't work.

Comment: You may have to boot into safe mode, and/or provide the installation media, to get any board-specific drivers loaded the first time.

Comment: Safe Mode would boot without problem, then?

Comment: If you are changing CPU manufacturer there might be a problem also. I.e. Intel / AMD.  All of this is correctable in various ways after the motherboard is changed.

Comment: Actually, I am still using an Intel processor, although upgrading from a 2nd gen to an 8th gen.

Comment: You should also consider licensing limitations. OEM Windows systems are limited to a motherboard. (Legally, not necessarily in code)

Comment: I linked to my other question with regards to the operating system.

Comment: I think it won't work, however there is a chance that Windows will use default drivers. The only way to confirm here is just try!

Comment: Well, if it works, everybody has to upvote my question!

Comment: It worked like a charm!  Somebody please post an answer so I can accept it (I hate answering my own questions).

Comment: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/135077-windows-7-installation-transfer-new-computer.html